# C# MVVM, Understanding when not to make a model

Tags: c#, mvvm

I Everyone.

I am a big fan of MVVM But need to clarify how I should Implement a general method that could be used across several view models.

Currently I have implemented a method in to a model to take a screen shot like so E.G.

Interface

```
public interface ICapture {
 void CaptureMethod();
}
```

This is the model that implements that interface

```
public class CaptureModel : ICapture {
    void CaptureMethod(){ //implement the code to take screen shot }
}
```

Now I want to execute a screen shot on one or multiple view models, so I would need to instantiate the and call the function like so.

```
public ViewModel(){
 void TakeScreenShotMethodOrCommandDontCare(){
   ICapture captureClass = new CaptureClass();
   captureClass.captureMethod
  }
}
```

Which just feels **WRONG** having to instantiate an instance of an object in order to call a function which will be taking a screenshot.

I suppose i could go in the view model and have capture screenshot method but that would lead to code duplication across all view models with that feature.

Maybe a static utility class but surely that would be expensive on the app.

I feel if I had an interface that was implemented by a base class then my view model could inherit from that base class and implement the base implementation on any view model I desire.

So to sum up my question, if you wanted to implement a method that captures screen shots and you like mvvm then where would you implement ??

Again many thanks to all that have taken the time to shine some light on this for me.

Comment: IMHO consider MVVM as a rule of thumb and not a dogma per-se. It is based of off the three tier data separation model and given fancy names. As long as the models generally look like POCO classes and the business logic stays on VMs you are fine. But on my last project I had business logic, specific to model operations, on the partial classes of based the models to process specific db business logic operations applicable to that model.

Comment: Hi megaMan, that my point the capture class isnt really a poco its not defining an object which will update in db or displayed to view so no properties at all, it is class that  only implements methods that I may use across multiple viewmodels. I noticed my post doesnt really explain that well, so i have extended it. Many Thanks

Comment: You really shouldn't post the same question on both StackOverflow and SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.

Comment: I know, I posted here first and realised that my question was more software architecture over being a coding issue, Will avoid doing so in future just wanted to create a bridge in the void I'd created here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has been found and involved injecting a service class in to the view model I wish to use the methods in.

Link to answer.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/380036/c-mvvm-understanding-when-not-to-make-a-model

Answer (score 0):

This is actually what I would consider well within the MVVM standard. When dealing with MVVM, I find it best to think about it this way. Your View should know only about your ViewModel and the ViewModel should know nothing of the View. The ViewModel should know about your model (or models) but the model should know nothing of the ViewModel or View.

So, here your Model is being instantiated in the ViewModel which is perfectly valid! In this case, your Model is the CaptureClass and the ViewModel knows that it can take a string from that and provide it to some View that may want to use it.

Model:

```
class CaptureClass : ICapture
{       
  public string CaptureShot()
  {
     string s = DependencyService.Get<ICapture>().CaptureShot();
     return s;
  }      
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CaptureViewModel(){

   private _captureText;

   public CaptureText
   {
       get{ return _captureText; }
       set{
           _captureText = value;
       }
   }

   public CaptureViewModel()
   {
       CaptureClass cc = new CaptureClass();
       _captureText = cc.CaptureShot();
   }
}
```

Now all you've got to do is hook it up to your View. Remember that the View knows which property to bind to so just set your DataContext either in the code behind or in XAML and then just bind the property in XAML like so:

```
<Label Content="{Binding CaptureText}" />
```

Comment: Hey Heisenberg, thanks for cooking up that crsytal clear explination of mvvm , I have grasped the concept of bindings. I was a little unclear in my original post at what I was getting, really I ant to know how one would implement a class of utility methods that one would like to use across multiple viewmodel.  I have modified the original post to clarify, Many Thanks